# Why is syrup added to a cake before frosting?

Tags: cake, decorating

Why is syrup added to the inside of a cake before frosting? Maybe the cream sticks better with each layer of cake?

Comment: Just wanted to mention, I'm from the UK and we very rarely add syrup to a cake as standard (apart from a drizzle cake), so it must be something to do with specific recipes!

Comment: Ditto for the US..

Comment: @Bee it's standard in home baking to use thinned down Apricot Jam as a "syrup" to stick on marzipan or other icing eg when making a fruit cake or Battenburg cake.

Comment: Those are specific types of cake though, both topped with royal icing or marzipan, the op is talking about topping with frosting and I'd never add syrup under that

Comment: Syruped cakes are the norm in Eastern cuisine (the geographical separation starts around Turkey, I suspect the origin of the practice is India). People in countries with syruped cakes are surprised at the idea of eating a cake which has not been soaked in syrup, just as people with countries are surprised at the idea of soaking it. But we are still talking about a standard, widespread practice, not about something rarely used in specialized recipes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brushing a cake with simple syrup before frosting is done to prevent the cake from drying out too quickly, and sometimes to add flavour (if a flavoured syrup is used instead of just water+sugar).

Comment: It also would be harder to add syrup after frosting. You'd either "flush" off the frosting, dilute it or end up with a puddle of syrup around the cake.

Answer (score 4):

The syrup is added to the cake before frosting so that is remains moist throughout. Also you can add flavours to your simple syrup to enhance the flavour like cinammon or star anise in banana cake and orange cake. For mango cake, you can simply add cardamom to syrup.
Avoid using simple syrup if it is already moist and delicate. It would destroy the cake.

Comment: `"It would destroy the cake."` Destroy how? Structurally?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas : the cake can't absorb the moisture and maintain structural integrity.  It either seeps out the bottom and makes a mess, or the cake starts breaking down and has a texture more like wet crumbs than cake.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas If the cake is already moist or too soft and you'll add simple syrup, it would make it soggy and heavy and it might collapse as it won't be able to hold that liquid for too long.

Answer (score 2):

Simple syrup add a great taste,  but be careful not to add too much syrup. The frosty will collapse. Just add 1/4 cup to each layer of your cake prior of frosting. Wait for an 1 hour to absorb the syrup prior of frosting. This happened to me for adding to much syrup. [image][image]